How do you get the XYZ coordinates of a point from a Maya Python script?
How do you get the numerical xyz components of a vertex in Maya from a Python script?

Extremely hard to find, but you have to use the maya.cmds.xform command in query mode

(Maya complete command list here)

Maya identifies objects in it by strings only. So you have to use the string that asks Maya for the vertices of the shape object you are querying. If you have a cube named pCube1, it's just pCube1.vtx[*]
# Get the raw numeric xyz values of pCube1
xyzs = cmds.xform( 'pCube1.vtx[*]', q=True, translation=True, worldSpace=True)

print( '%d component entries' % len( xyzs ) )
for i in range( 0, len(xyzs), 3 ):
  x = xyzs[ i + 0 ]
  y = xyzs[ i + 1 ]
  z = xyzs[ i + 2 ]
  print( '( %8.3f %8.3f %8.3f )' % (x, y, z ) )


@JonSG, well, that works for the 1st vertex, but I couldn't make that approach work for after that (cannot unpack non-iterable float object)

ahh I see now that xyzs is shaped differently than I anticipated. thanks
